# How to draw phase diagram of this hamiltonian?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning how to plot gradient and Hamiltonian systems.  The system is thus.
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x' = −\sin^2 x\sin y\\
y' = −2 \sin x \cos x \cos y.
\end{array}\right.
$$
I know that because this is a Hamiltonian system, the phase diagram is just the level sets of the Hamiltonian, the problem is, I'm not sure how to find the actual Hamiltonian.  Integrating the x and y prime expressions in terms of x and y respectively don't seem to give me something that makes much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hamiltonian system is
$$
x'=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial y},\quad y'=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x},
$$
thus, you need to integrate $x'$ with respect to $y$ or $y'$ with respect to $x$:
$$
H(x,y)=-\int (-\sin^2 x\sin y)\,dy=-\sin^2x\sin y+c(x).$$
In order to obtain $c(x)$, we can differentiate $H(x,y)$:
$$
H_x= -2\sin x\cos x\sin y+c'(x).
$$
Hence, $c'(x)=0$ and, if we take $c=0$, $H(x,y)=-\sin^2x\sin y$.